# Variable usage in C

Tags: c, variables

I'm a novice in C and came across code that seemed peculiar to me,

```
extern int num;
int counter;

void init_counter() {
    counter = 0;
}

int return_position() {
    int pos = counter;
    counter = counter * num;
    return pos;
}
```

What is the point of the pos variable?
why can't I just do:

```
extern int num;
int counter;

void init_counter() {
    counter = 0;
}

int return_position() {
    counter = counter * num;
    return counter;
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Your second example returns a different value than the first one.

Comment: Because the original function returns the value as it was *before* altering it.

Comment: `pos` holds the *old* value of `counter` (before it gets updated). You can very easily test this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `pos` variable is to preserve (and then return) the *original* value of `counter`. Your "alternative" version returns the *new* value of `counter`, which is a completely different behavior.

An attempt to achieve the intended behavior without an extra variable might look as follows

```
int return_position() 
{
  counter = counter * num;
  return counter / num;
}
```

but it is harder to read and it fails for zero `num`.

Answer (score 0):

as been said the two codes are not the same and pos holds the old value of counter
let's say after init_counter call you assign 1 to counter and num is 3 and we run `return_position()` 3 times:
it's important to understand how to follow your code
the reason I decided that counter = 1 because `counter = counter*num;` will always yield 0 unless counter is something else...

```
counter = 1, num = 3
```

so on the first entry

```
pos = 1
counter = 3*1
```

and we return 1

next round

```
counter = 3, num = 3
pos = 3
counter = 3*3 = 9
return 3
```

next round

```
counter = 9, num = 3
pos = 9
counter = 9 * 3 = 27
return 9
```

so if we've printed just the returned values we would get
"
1
3 
9
"
counter is equal to 27

a more convenient way is to create a table of variables and update it as we did before . ofc there're debugging tools that will help you to do so but try at first your way with pen and paper

notice that if we assume that counter was initialized just by init_counter()
and then and only then we'd call  `return_position()` 3 times
we'd get only 0's which is pointless:)

good luck on your learning quest